# Microsoft patch : KB3203859 and KB3196718 throwing run time error for Visual Basic application

Tags: windows-server-2003, visual-basic

We have a windows server 2003 VDM, in which VB applications are throwing
this run time error:

[image]

However after uninstalling KB3203859 and KB3196718 Microsoft patches, the run time error is gone. I tried to find the connection between the error and these security patches but had no luck.

After further investigation I found that oleaut32.dll is throwing the error. Has the patch corrupted oleaut32.dll?

Comment: Do the errors go away if you roll the patches back? You should consider a migration plan as Server 2003 is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes after rolling back patch, errors go away.